# Storing metadata about a numeric value field

Tags: mysql, metadata, field, numeric

I am trying to solve a simple problem. We have a bunch of numeric fields (lab result values). I would like the users to be able to indicate some common scenarios about the fields:

- Data not available ("no data")
- Data not readable ("illegible")
- Unkown.
  etc.

I can definitely create a sidecar field that goes with each field and storing a "null" in the original field which would indicate that the numeric value should be obtained from the sidecar field. This solution still enables me to perform numeric value operations on the field, and if needed, I can look in to the sidecar field to find out why the data was missing (null).

I would like to know how you might go about solving this problem, and what are the best ways to address metadata issues like this.

Answer (score 1):

Really, I think you've already got hold of the best option for this situation. If you're going to need to keep track of more than 2 or 3 options for this metadata you might want to consider creating a separate table to store the descriptions to save on headaches for future code.

```
TABLE lab_results
  id INT PK
  ...
  meta INT NULL
  meta_reason_id INT NULL

TABLE meta_reasons
  id INT PK
  desc VARCHAR
```

Comment: Appreciate your response. I considered a separate table, but the problem of JOIN becomes harder very fast, especially when the system needs to display thousands of these rows in an excel file or a web page.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to be JOINed, but it is much simpler than modifying the source code each time you want to add another reason code.